# Form's lost focus in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, focus

This may be a simple C# question but I need a solution.

I have two forms, **form1** and **form2**, with **form1** having a *button*. On the *click* of the button, I want to show **form2**. When **form2** looses focus I want to hide it (**form2**). How can I do this? I tried to subscribe to the *LostFocus* event of **form2**,  but it isn't working.

Please help me with this.

Note -- I use .Net 2.0

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `Deactivate` event handler

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question, I think you actually want to trap deactivation. Button handler inside your main form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form childForm = new Form();
    childForm.Deactivate += delegate
    {
        childForm.Close();
    };

    childForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: From her description, she probably wants .Hide(), not .Close(), but +1 anyway