# hide form when user clicks elsewhere

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

i have application with one form, which i developed in c#.  I would like to hide the form when a user clicks somewhere else then on the form or on the notification icon (in system tray). How could i do that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570021/forms-lost-focus-in-c

Comment: I am not 100% sure you can do it with the standard event exposed by Visual Studio in the designer but if you could attach to the DeActivate event, or form lost focus, then you can call form.Hide

Comment: ah, sorry didn't search enough in the old posts.. post an anwser, an i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure you can do it with the standard event exposed by Visual Studio in the designer but if you could attach to the DeActivate event, or form lost focus, then you can call form.Hide